# IF and OR combination for cell values in a Colum(s)

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

In cell `Q49` I have: `=IF(COUNTIF(W5:W35,"OK")=ROWS(W5:W35),"GOOD","WARNING!")`

Now, it works perfect with one column, but I would like to add more "columns" 
(for example add `X5:X35` and `Y5:Y35`)

That should make excel look for "OK" in the designated columns.
This is what i tried but it didn't work:

`=IF(COUNTIF(W5:W35,X5:X35,Y5:Y35,"OK")=ROWS(W5:W35,X5:X35,Y5:Y35),"GOOD","WARNING!")`

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIF(W5:Y35,"OK")=COUNTA(W5:Y35),"GOOD","WARNING!")`

Comment: How would it look like if had "stuff" in between the columns(lets assume one would be located on A5:A35 and next is on Z5:Z35)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the column checks and use "AND"

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(W5:W35,"OK")=ROWS(W5:W35),COUNTIF(X5:X35,"OK")=ROWS(X5:X35),COUNTIF(Y5:Y35,"OK")=ROWS(Y5:Y35)),"GOOD","WARNING!")
```

Comment: OMG That was perfect!! Thank you sooo much Chris!!